# Running JAR file on AIX via KornShell script

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh, aix

I run the following command on my AIX machine.

```
/usr/java6_64/jre/bin/java -jar myapp.jar
```

Then, things look fine. The JAR file connects to the database and does whatever it needs to do.

But I need to put this command (plus a few others) in a script.

So I created a KornShell (ksh) script file called "script.ksh" to do the above.

```
#!/bin/ksh
/usr/java6_64/jre/bin/java -jar myapp.jar
```

But it is giving me the following exception:

```
EXCEPTION:  TerminateProcessException: Cannot connect to the database.
 java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
```

Now, there is a "lib" folder in the same location as the JAR file and script.ksh file where the JDBC driver is located.

Is there something I am missing in the shell script? Like classpath? I tried setting the classpath in the script with

```
CLASSPATH=/home/path/to/lib/*.jar
```

But it still gave me the error. Looks like it can't find the driver. Any help?

Comment: hmm just tried -classpath /home/path/to/lib/jdbc.jar and it is working. So it must be to do with classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Try exporting the `CLASSPATH` variable.